# Cordova-Plugin-Contacts can't remove contact field

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, contacts

I'm retrieving all contacts from the system like this:

```
 navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function (contacts) {});
```

And then I pick one contact from the array (e.g. `var myContact = contacts[4];`). The contact has two or more phone number fields.

Shortened version of the contact's object:

```
{
    phoneNumbers: [
        {id: 0, type: "work", value: "123123123"},
        {id: 1, type: "home", value: "3216532425"}
    ]
}
```

When I remove one of the both contact fields from the phoneNumbers array and then save the contact, it still has both numbers on the device. When I re-retrieve the contact it has both numbers again. (Tested on iOS 9.3 with plugin version 2.0.1)
I can't find any hint in the documentation if I do something wrong or if the plugin is behaving wrong.

I have created a demo script, which reproduces the issue. You can use it for testing:
http://pastebin.com/XRdREL3Y

You might want to remove line 25 which removes the test contact in the end.

Shortened version of the demo script:

```
navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function (contacts) {
    // Pick a contact
    // (Make sure the contact has more than two phoneNumberFields)
    var myContact = contacts[4]; 

    // Remove the second phone number
    delete myContact.phoneNumbers[1];

    myContact.save(function () {
        console.log("Success");
        /// You will see, that the contact still has all it's previous phone numbers
    }, function () {
        console.error("error while saving");
    });

}, function () {
    console.error("Could not access conacts.");
});
```

**So the question is: Does the plugin behave wrong? If not; how do you remove contact fields?**

Comment: Possibly related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698798/cordova-contacts-plugin-contact-data-is-duplicating-instead-of-overwriting-conta?rq=1